# In R, creating table and plot when some column data is zero

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I'm learning to use R, and I want to do an analysis of my customers and the distribution of them into categories. This is an example of my data:

[image: example data]

I want to know how many customers (cards) have tickets in A, B or C, and the amount spend on each of these categories, and then do the same thing but for each type of segment.

I want to do a bar chart with the percentage of tickets in each category of all my customers and then 3 charts of each segment.

Heres an example of what I want to get:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QXuO.png)

The thing is that there are cards that have 0 tickets on that category.
I've been thinking that it might work to add a column beside each category, adding for example an "if the row has tickets in category A", then put A in that row, so maybe its easier to create a column?

If you think that might work, how could I run that?
Sorry but I'm very new on R and I have a huge data base :(

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: please explain what you have tried and/or any errors you are getting

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to make a great reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The `tapply` function would seem to be useful. You need to be more specific about how you want the subtotals presented. Are we supposed to `sum(<all-categories-of-Sales>`? Or are we supposed to intuit that you wanted the 'SalesA' to be associated with 'TickA'?

Comment: Thank you all, I've post an image of the results I want to get, hope that explains better.